# How to add the album art to a .mp3 file using mp3agic?

Tags: java, id3v2, mp3agic

I have been trying to set the album art of a mp3 file using the mp3agic library in java. The following code snippet is what i used to do so. Unfortunately this isnt working. The saved image file does not contain the album art nor the set title. Also, the program compiles with no error.

```
File img = new File("img.jpg");
imgLink[1]="http://"+imgLink[1];
URL url = new URL(imgLink[1]);
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, img);
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) img.length()];
id3v2Tag.setTitle("Something");
id3v2Tag.setAlbumImage(bytes, "image/jpg");
mp3file.save("something.mp3");
```

Any help regarding this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The above code works. It wasn't showing properly on the folder I was working with.  When I opened the file with iTunes it showed up. It's probably some fault with windows.